# django makemigrations does not work

Tags: python, django

I want to make migrations for `game.characters`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'django_summernote',

    'lucifer',
    'users',
    'posts',

    'game',
    'game.characters',
]
```

I use the command

```
python lucifer/manage.py makemigrations users posts game game.characters
python lucifer/manage.py migrate
```

**`App 'game.characters' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?`**

I can't understand why?

here is my `game.characters`

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from game.quests.models import Quest


class Character(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        )

    nickname = models.CharField(
        max_length=8,
        )

    level = models.IntegerField(
        default=1,
        )

    JOB_CHOICE = (
        ('killer', '나이트'),
        ('gunshoter', '야만전사'),
        ('monster', '팔라딘'),
        )

    job = models.CharField(
        max_length=4,
        choices=JOB_CHOICE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        )
```

Tree

```
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── lucifer
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── game
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── characters
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── models
│   │           ├── __init__.py
│   │           └── character.py
│   ├── lucifer
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── development.py
│   │   │   ├── partials
│   │   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   │   ├── base.py
│   │   │   │   ├── database.py
│   │   │   │   ├── static.py
│   │   │   │   └── summernote.py
│   │   │   └── production.py
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── views
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   └── home.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── manage.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `makemigrations` command takes the [app label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.label), which is `characters`, not `game.characters`:

```
python lucifer/manage.py makemigrations characters
```

Comment: Fantasic! Thank you @Alasdair!